# How to use promises with Angular.js and $resource with query string?

Tags: angularjs, promise

What's the best way to handle promises in Angular.js with a resource that expects a query string / parameters passed to it?  I've seen the job of $q handled in the factory, controller and router but I'm not sure how to handle it in any case when there's parameters involved.
So if this is the factory :

```
angular.module(Animals, ['$resource', '$route', '$location', function($resource, $route, $location) {
  return $resource('http://thezoo.com/animals', { query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}});
}]);
```

and this is the controller:

```
Animals.query({size="med",gender='f'});
```

then how should this best be handled using promises?  The call to the external resource can take quite long.

Answer (score 3):

Really late to the party, but I found this page from Google.
If you want to use a resource, but maybe you want to get data from your query method before you continue (maybe you're writing this in a resolve or something), you can do this.

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
Resource.query({params}, function (response) {
  someData = response;
  deferred.resolve(someData);
});
return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: There's no need to wrap a $resource in another promise. As of Angular 1.1/1.2, the $promise property of the resource object is fully then-able (and resolve-able), and contains references back to the $resource object itself.

Comment: @XMLilley If you were going to use a resource to get a particular object in your resolve, would you just return something like Resource.get($route.current.params.id)?

Comment: exactly so. I have an app right now with a Service that does the same thing, including grabbing a value off of $routeParams.

Comment: if you are using $resource, you do not need to use $q as promise is already baked in.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what you're trying to accomplish.

`$resource` methods will not return promises. They will return empty arrays or objects that are be populated when data is returned by the server.

If you want a method that returns a promise, you can write one that uses `$http` directly.